# How to compare with above record in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm posting sample data which I got after executing my query to avoid any confusion.
Here is the sample data :

```
ID  Original    NET LEVELS
1000    2122    8534    1
1000    2123    8500    1
1000    2123    8500    2
1000    2123    8500    3
1000    2124    8577    1
1000    2124    8577    2
1000    2124    8578    3
1000    2124    8578    4
```

How can I get this output :

```
ID  Original    NET LEVELS Equal 
1000    2122    8534    1   No 
1000    2123    8500    1   YES
1000    2123    8500    2   YES
1000    2123    8500    3   YES
1000    2124    8577    1   YES
1000    2124    8577    2   YES
1000    2124    8578    3   NO
1000    2124    8578    4   YES
```

Actually here in need to compare every row with above row based on the combination of original and NET and Levels columns. If both the rows are equal then 'YES' and below row and above row not equal then 'NO'

Comment: How does the second row get a `'YES'` based on your rule?

Comment: What determines the order if your data `ORDER BY ORIGINAL, NET, LEVELS`? Have you tried anything so far? What were the problems you faced or errors? Have you had a look at `LAG`?

Comment: You could use `LEAD` to compare with next row or `LAG` to compare with previous row

Comment: based on the original ,Net columns first record is different set and not related to second row

Comment: can you elaborate with reference to the sample data and expected result ?

Comment: @Squirrel I have given sample data and output also . can you please have a look

Comment: In your sample data, "based on the combination of original and NET and Levels columns", none row is equal to above row.

Comment: but we could not relate your explanation with the sample data & expected result. What you explain and what you shown (expected result) does not tally

Comment: @GordonLinoff first record is different from second record based on original column and Net Column

Comment: @OtoShavadze please don't consider Levels column only consider Original column and based on the above record compare below record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be below query will help you to resolve your problem.

```
CREATE table #test
(
    ID int
    ,oringal int
    ,NET int
    ,Levels int
)

insert into  #test
select 1000   , 2122 ,   8534  ,  1
union select 1000,    2123  ,  8500   , 1
union select 1000,    2123  ,  8500   , 2
union select 1000,    2123  ,  8500   , 3
union select 1000,    2124  ,  8577   , 1
union select 1000,    2124  ,  8577   , 2
union select 1000,    2124  ,  8578   , 3
union select 1000,    2124  ,  8578   , 4 

SELECT 
    ID
    ,oringal
    ,NET
    ,Levels
    ,CASE WHEN oringal=ISNULL(orignalLAG,orignalLEAD) AND NET= ISNULL(NETLAG,NETLEAD) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' ENd as Eual

FROM
(
select  
*
,LAG(oringal) OVER  (PARTITION BY oringal   ORDER BY oringal  ) as orignalLAG
,LAG(NET)  OVER  (PARTITION BY oringal  ORDER BY oringal  )  as NETLAG
,LEAD(oringal) OVER  (PARTITION BY oringal ORDER BY oringal  ) as orignalLEAD
,LEAD(NET)  OVER  (PARTITION BY oringal ORDER BY oringal  )  as NETLEAD
from #test
)q
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that every first unequal should get a 'No', which means you made a mistake in your question. If not, I don't get the logic. You might try this code:

```
WITH CTE AS -- end previous statement with semi-colon
(
    SELECT ID, Original, NET, LEVELS, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NET, LEVELS ORDER BY NET)) AS RowNumb
    FROM TableA
)

SELECT *, CASE WHEN C.RowNumb = 1 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Equal 
FROM CTE AS C
LEFT JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C.RowNumb = C2.RowNumb - 1
```